# Regarding the no right turns except buses does this also apply to school buses?

Tags: traffic

Since the bus lanes in NYC also apply to school buses I also assumed the the No right turns except buses also applied to school buses. Am I right?

Comment: That seems like a fair and proper assumption.  Is there some reason you might doubt it that would make this a good question?  (Just curious, did you mean "*no right turn*" or "*right turn only*" except buses?  Because most bus lanes I have seen can be used by cars for right turns, but only buses can go straight.)

Comment: @MichaelHall  I have seen those for a situation where they have a place reserved for buses to discharge and take on passengers, and no other vehicles is allowed in.

Comment: The only difference between a school bus and a general transit system bus is who is allowed to ride (students vs. everyone). But when it comes to the reasons for bus lanes: more efficient movement (buses hold a lot of people, whether school buses or otherwise), safety (for stopping, for passengers crossing the street, etc.) - there is no fundamental difference between a school bus and any other bus.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact The difference may be that some buses are part of a municipal mass transit system, and there are often regulations that apply only to vehicles in that system. But there might not be room on the signs for that level of detail.

Comment: @Barmar There are certainly regulations that apply to school buses that don't apply to mass transit buses and vice versa. For example, at least in my area, you can have people standing in a mass transit bus while the bus is in motion, but not in a school bus. But those are regulations for the **vehicles** and not for the **roads**.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I'm not saying this specific law is one of the differencs, just that buses are not all treated equally. Another example: there are dedicated lanes for buses to enter/exit depots, and only the buses that use those depots can use them.

Answer (score 9):

### A school bus is a [bus](https://law.justia.com/codes/new-york/2022/vat/title-5/article-19-a/509-a/#:%7E:text=As%20used%20in%20this%20article,addition%20to%20the%20driver%20and)

> § 509-a. Definitions. As used in this article the term: (1) bus shall mean every motor vehicle, owned, leased, rented or otherwise controlled by a motor carrier, which (a) is a school bus … [or other things that aren’t school buses]